# Laravel: Nesting query join results in a sub array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

**NOTE** Please do not suggest using Eloquent, this is specifically for the Laravel query builder.

For performance reasons we are using Query Builder to retrieve results from a table:

```
DB::table('posts')->get();
```

If we then want to join a relation onto that query:

```
DB:table('posts')
    ->leftJoin('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id')
    ->get();
```

The results are merged into the array of each post:

```
[
    'id'                => 1,
    'title'             => 'My Blog Post',
    'content'           => '<h1>This is a post</h1><p>hello world</p>',
    'post_author'       => 'Billy',
    'comment'           => 'This is a comment',
    'comment_author'    => 'Andrew',
]
```

How can we have the joined results placed into a nested array? Such as:

```
[
    'id'                => 1,
    'title'             => 'My Blog Post',
    'content'           => '<h1>This is a post</h1><p>hello world</p>',
    'post_author'       => 'Billy',
    'comment'           => [
        'id'                => 22,
        'comment'           => 'This is a comment',
        'comment_author'    => 'Andrew',            
    ],
]
```

Comment: Relations are only used in case of Eloquent. Laravel Query Builder does not handle relations. @SougataBose

Comment: What is the issue with the format return by query?

Comment: Are looking for some thing like GROUP BY in MySQL for grouping all the comments for each post ?

Comment: @SougataBose The question clearly states not to use Eloquent.........

Comment: In laravel you can't get above output using query builder. For this either you will need to write your own classes and functions which can then return your desired format of output.

Answer (score 3):

Dont think its doable out of the box without Eloquent.

You can go the primitive route:

```
$results = DB:table('posts')
    ->leftJoin('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id')
    ->select('posts.*', 'comments.*', 'comments.id as comments_id')
    ->get(); 

foreach($results as &$result) 
{ 
    $result['comment'] = [
        'id' => $result['comment_id'], 
        'comment' => $result['comment'], 
        'comment_author' => $result['comment_author']
    ]; 
    unset($result['comment_author'], $result['comment_id']);
}
```

Comment: I wish eloquent had a more subtle way of handling results, at least as an option.

Comment: Your solution does not group all comments of each post as a nested-array, actually each post will appear N times, when N is its comments number.

Comment: This will make the query very slower, as if there are more than 10000+ post, then query itself will take some seconds to executes

Comment: @JagadishMeghval the question was how to get join results in a nested manner. It has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: Does eloquent the same as on this answer?

Answer (score 1):

Since you work with DB facade and not Eloquent, and cannot use built-in `with()` method, you have to implement it yourself:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->get()->toArray();
$comments = DB::table('comments')->get()->toArray();

foreach($posts as &$post)
{
    $post->comments = array_filter($comments, function($comment) use ($post) {
        return $comment->post_id === $post->id;
    });
}

return $posts;
```

If you want to get rid of `post_id` for comments entries, you can do:

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->get()->toArray();
$comments = DB::table('comments')->get()->toArray();

foreach($posts as &$post)
{
    $comments = array_filter($comments, function($comment) use ($post) {
        return $comment->post_id === $post->id;
    });

    $post->comments = array_map(function ($comment) {
        unset($comment->id);
        return $comment;
    }, $comments);
}

return $posts;
```

(I guess the runtime would be similar to `with()`, since after-all MySql does not provide this functionality out-of-the-box).

Answer (score 0):

Here some new information:

```
$data= $DB->select("select posts.*,comments from posts left join comments on posts.id = comments.post_id");
```

I am not sure it is work or not but you can try

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31393825)

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

```
$data= $DB->select("select *,(select json_agg(datas) from (select * from comments where posts.id=comments.post_id) as datas) as comments from posts;");
```

But you may need to decode at comments as well

Answer (score 0):

```
$products = Category::with('product')->get(array('category.qty','category.product_id','category.net_unit_price as price'));

    foreach ($products as $p){
        $pl['name'] = $p->product->name;
        $pl['image'] = $p->product->image;
        unset($pl->product);
    }
```