# Laravel: How to load joined tables into the subarrays?

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have 2 tables:

```
User:
id
schedule_id
name

Schedules:
id
date
```

I execute a query using `eager loading`:

```php
User::with (['schedules'])->get()->first();
```

And got result like this:

```php
[
    'id' => '3',
    'schedule' => [
        'id' => '13',
        'date' => '20.11.2020',
    ],
    'name' => 'John',
];
```

But when I execute a similar query using `join`,

```php
User::join ('schedules', 'user.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')->get()->first();
```

I got result like this, with merged arrays:

```php
[
    'id' => '13',
    'date' => '20.11.2020',
    'name' => 'John',
];
```

**How can I got a result with separated arrays, using join in Eloquent?**

*Note: in raw PHP and PDO I always got separated arrays for any queries with join.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Nesting query join results in a sub array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673556/laravel-nesting-query-join-results-in-a-sub-array)

Comment: Yes, this is the same question, but the answer just suggest manually to map columns using aliases. Maybe a more comfortable way exists.

Answer (score 2):

Data coming from a database query will always be formatted as a flat array, that's just how databases work. Eloquent has a lot of magic going on behind the scene's that is going to map the correct related values to the correct models in the collection.

When using joins, there is no way for Eloquent to know what data should be mapped to which relation or property.

If you want to use join queries, you either will have to use aliases for these properties on the models. Or you can manually map the properties the way you want them before using the data.

Comment: Ok, as I understand, Laravel performs multiple queries when using eager loading. But I always got a separated arrays using raw PDO in PHP. How PHP knows what columns should be mapped into the subarray?

Comment: Indeed, whenever you load a relation through eloquent, a new query is performed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I can suggest a more suitable way to get results ordered by relation's column in Laravel's Eloquent.

You should use 2 queries.

Firstly just get only ids, but ordered by any relation's column.
(You can't order results by relation's column using eager loading)

```php
$idsRaw = User::join ('schedules', 'user.schedule_id', '=', 'schedules.id')
    ->select ('users.id')
    ->orderBy ('schedules.date')
    ->get ()->toArray ();
$ids = \array_column ($idsRaw, 'id');
```

Secondly get good results with subarrays for relations using eager loading:

```php
User::with (['schedules'])
    ->whereIn ('user.id', \implode (',', $ids))
    ->orderByRaw('FIELD(' . $ids . ',' . \implode(',', $ids) . ')')
    ->get()->toArray ();
```

Advantages:

You don't need manually map columns and aliases into subarrays (It may be very difficult if you have many relations).

Disadvantages:

This method works as slow as much ids you have.

Yes, if you have a thousands ids in the query, you should use one complex query with joins for all relations and manually map aliases into subarrays for best performance.