# Laravel Query Builder: Join creates two objects instead of one object with an array

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder, eloquent-relationship

The structure of models/tables is:

**1. ShopItem**

- shopitem_id
- shopitem_title
- shopitem_price

**2. Colours**

- colour_id
- colour_name

**3. ShopItemColours**

- id
- **shopitem_id   (foreign key)**
- **colour_id     (foreign key)**

I used query builder:

```
$shopItems = ShopItem::where('shopitem_id', 33)
        ->join('shop_item_colours', 'shop_item_colours.shop_item_id', '=', 'shop_items.id')
        ->join('colours', 'colours.colour_id', '=', 'shop_item_colours.colours_id')
        ->get();
```

Expected output is like this, where the ShopItemColours are an array.

```
{
    'shopitem_id': 33
    'shopitem_title': 'item title'
    'shopitem_price': 123
    'colour_name': ['black', 'white']
}
```

However, instead of a single row with an array of ShopItemColours, I get two rows, each row having different Colour item.

```
[
    {
        'shopitem_id': 33
        'shopitem_title': 'item title'
        'shopitem_price': 123
        'colour_name': 'black'
    },
    {
        'shopitem_id': 33
        'shopitem_title': 'item title'
        'shopitem_price': 123
        'colour_name': 'white'
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you in advance!

Comment: Laravel simply execute your query and get two records. If you want a single row where colour_name is an array of possible colors, you have to do it manually

Comment: You must use `groupBy` statement by `shopitem_id` to getting single record. But you can't get raw response as array for `colour_name`. Groupby provides SQL Aggregation functions usages, like count, sum, concat etc.  You can use this functions for getting data from database and play... Related question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41673556/laravel-nesting-query-join-results-in-a-sub-array 

But, I recommend redefine your data structure and relations. Also use Eloquent ORM.